# MySQL - Repeat a varchar according to the leading zeros

Tags: mysql

Using MYSQL, I have a varchar column and I need to execute a select, repeating/padding the return value according to the leading zeros, for example:

| ID | Return |
| --- | --- |
| 000001 | XXXXX000001 |
| 011111 | X011111 |

Basically if the string have leading zeros I need to padding the return value with the same X value
Is it even possible? I've been searching about, I've tried LPAD, TRIMM, but I can't figure it out

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number of leading `0`s of the `ID` with:

```
LENGTH(ID) - LENGTH(ID + 0)
```

or:

```
LENGTH(ID) - LENGTH(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM ID))
```

Use this number with the function [`REPEAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_repeat) to create a string with repeating `X`s and then concatenate it to `ID`:

```
SELECT ID, 
       CONCAT(REPEAT('X', LENGTH(ID) - LENGTH(ID + 0)), ID) `Return`
FROM tablename
```

Or:

```
SELECT ID, 
       CONCAT(REPEAT('X', LENGTH(ID) - LENGTH(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM ID))), ID) `Return`
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=550b3c824c0f75c22fde42ce88568970).

Answer (score 1):

If your values are always Numeric with leading zero then
try this

```
select id, lpad(id,2*length(id)-length(id+0),'X') as `return` from test
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dd53bf387365e8aea13506e1928bf83e)